# How to find differences in two sheet index then copy differences into another sheet index

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyverse

can someone please help me with this script in R
I actually don't know how to write the script.
this is what I want

I have a dataset that contains two different sheet
sheet 1 is named James
sheet 2 is named Bruce

I want to compare the two sheet James and Bruce using diff parameters or column

for Sheet1 (James) the parameter or column name is called "Confirm Code"
for sheet2 (Bruce) the parameter or column name is called "Reference"

I want the result to show me what's in James and not in Bruce which would come out as NA.

COPY what's in James that's not in Bruce to another sheet and name the sheet James VAR

COPY whats in Bruce that's not in James to another sheet and name it Bruce Var

An example is the one I just performed using excel, I want the same thing using R script. thanks

[image]

UPDATE UPDATE
here is the dataset below

Kindly see james Dataset below
Merchant    Recipient   Network Provider    Type    FaceValue   Date    Status  Net Val M Ref   Confirm Code    Tranx ID
SEAMAFIXER  8036638190  MCN CSW Airtime 10000   05/03/2021 0:00 Successful  9750    77352c77d0e5459789de8305730215df    2021030500000923904229397   2103058036638190120
SEAMAFIXER  7035471431  MCN CSW Airtime 10000   05/03/2021 0:00 Successful  9750    eff681b9716e4f559cc258c38c98507d    2021030500001003808058125   2103057035471431281
SEAMAFIXER  8037291170  MCN CSW Airtime 10000   05/03/2021 0:00 Successful  9750    64ec355e6dc844fb999098c11e493437    2021030500001031602687683   2103058037291170986
MORUFAT 7066994246  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 0:00 Successful  480 000006210305000042335138858174  2021030500004510105381114   2103050000531640792
OPONA   7049587980  MCN CSW Data    300 05/03/2021 0:01 Successful  287.4   BB88B5D94F9F490D8C7605DB2998904A    2021030500013156906225325   2103050001403684526
STANLEY 7039555954  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 0:01 Successful  477.5   SBP1310477351   2021030500014422205381372   2103050001523220139
STANLEY 9130078373  MCN CSW Data    2000    05/03/2021 0:02 Successful  1910    SBP000001210305000209100174071647   2021030500021196802688150   2103050002203575056
STANLEY 7030104764  MCN CSW Data    100 05/03/2021 0:02 Successful  95.5    SBP1310481102   2021030500023319307044836   2103050002414711929
STANLEY 8144791686  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 0:02 Successful  477.5   SBP000001210305000231100010646086   2021030500023325604229833   2103050002412320838
WEMBA   8104686137  MCN CSW Data    300 05/03/2021 0:02 Successful  289.5   Ref2021030423023741-9   2021030500023936702688271   2103050002473164596
MORUFAT 9031854650  MCN CSW Data    200 05/03/2021 0:03 Successful  192 000006210305000255887561541158  2021030500030088808058831   2103050003091469623
STANLEY 9033942149  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 0:03 Successful  477.5   SBP1310482928   2021030500031469503308082   2103050003231606090
OPONA   7066475616  MCN CSW Data    200 05/03/2021 0:05 Successful  191.6   304F9AD6BAA14345A00CD0A2A405D604    2021030500051352205382226   2103050005221639551
OPONA LADDER    8163737378  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 21:55    Successful  482.5   61480816373737820210305215536       2103052155364088772
OPONA LADDER    7038302679  MCN CSW Data    1500    05/03/2021 21:55    Successful  1447.5  63750703830267920210305215514       2103052155153229255
WEMBA   7038788822  MCN CSW Data    1500    05/03/2021 21:55    Successful  1447.5  Ref2021030520551122-84      2103052155132078269
OPONA   9037163970  MCN CSW Data    100 05/03/2021 21:53    Transaction Declined    95.8    84771DA669AC40AFBC899F54B7D15E0D        2103052153517389341
OPONA LADDER    8139598533  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 21:52    Transaction Declined    482.5   32190813959853320210305215159       2103052152001545858
OPONA LADDER    7061261254  MCN CSW Data    100 05/03/2021 21:48    Successful  96.5    74150706126125420210305214853       2103052148543299615
OPONA   8160384574  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 21:47    Transaction Declined    479 62BB50815A6B4D5693C29152AB3F06B6        2103052147191090354
OPONA LADDER    8036958609  MCN CSW Data    100 05/03/2021 21:47    Transaction Declined    96.5    47730803695860920210305214717       2103052147172579196
OPONA LADDER    8134675997  MCN CSW Data    1500    05/03/2021 21:47    Successful  1447.5  276908134675997202103052147028423       2103052147032553149
WEMBA   8102801556  MCN CSW Data    1200    05/03/2021 21:47    Successful  1158    Ref202103052047002-12       2103052147021005875
STANLEY 8137989325  MCN CSW Data    5000    05/03/2021 21:46    Successful  4775    SBP000001210305214656100351453835       2103052146591335636
OPONA LADDER    8167985479  MCN CSW Data    500 05/03/2021 21:46    Successful  479 6ABAEECBC06375057761028050950509        2103052146571238439
OPONA LADDER    8107047178  MCN CSW Data    100 05/03/2021 21:46    Transaction Declined    96.5    64450810704717820210305214635       2103052146362836975
OPONA LADDER    7033050336  MCN CSW Data    100 05/03/2021 21:46    Transaction Declined    96.5    50780703305033620210305214611       2103052146121603154

Bruce dataset
Reference   Type    Account Date_Created    DistributorRef  TRANX ID
2021030500000923904229397   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:00 19721   2103058036638190120
2021030500001003808058125   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:00 19721   2103057035471431281
2021030500001031602687683   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:00 19721   2103058037291170986
2021030500004510105381114   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:00 19721   2103050000531640792
2021030500013156906225325   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:01 19721   2103050001403684526
2021030500014422205381372   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:01 19721   2103050001523220139
2021030500021196802688150   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:02 19721   2103050002203575056
2021030500023319307044836   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:02 19721   2103050002414711929
2021030500023325604229833   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:02 19721   2103050002412320838
2021030500023936702688271   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:02 19721   2103050002473164596
2021030500030088808058831   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:03 19721   2103050003091469623
2021030500031469503308082   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:03 19721   2103050003231606090
2021030500051352205382226   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:05 19721   2103050003593501665
2021030500051870107045507   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:05 19721   2103050004318589635
2021030500054012507045647   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:05 19721   2103050004439248876
2021030500062158606226477   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:06 19721   2103050004481737976
2021030500063036501735063   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:06 19721   2103050004593616931
2021030500063730503308566   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:06 19721   2103050005221639551
2021030500072107704230363   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:07 19721   2103050005276790762
2021030500072696007046098   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:07 19721   2103050005483950219
2021030500074582102689356   Vend    RESELLER    05/03/2021 0:07 19721   2103050006303993014

Comment: You need to learn how to to present a reproducible example in R. It appears the data is in Excel, so perhaps the first task is to do the transfer? At any rate do a search on "reproducible example in R".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have loaded the datasets as a `data.frame()` I think this should work:

```
JamesVAR <- James[!James$`Confirm Code` %in% Bruce$Reference,]
write.csv(JamesVAR, "JamesVAR.csv")

BruceVAR <- Bruce[!Bruce$Reference %in% James$`Confirm Code`,]
write.csv(BruceVAR, "BruceVAR.csv")
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that the data is yet in an R object.

Comment: Hi ...i just want something that look exactly like the picture . thank you

Comment: I recommend you save the EXCEL files as CSV files (go to Save as and select csv in the drop down menu). You can then load them into R using `James <- read.csv("james.csv")` and `Bruce <- read.csv("bruce.csv")`. Then the above code should work. I reccomend you don't use spaces in the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two data frames such as

```
a <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y = c("p","q","r"))
a
  x y
1 1 p
2 2 q
3 3 r

b <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y = c("j","q","l"))
b
  x y
1 1 j
2 2 q
3 3 l

library(dplyr)
intersect(a,b)
  x y
1 2 q
```

You'll see the matched values popped out using intersect() function here from [dplyr](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) package. You can easily extract these similar values.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question. The data is in Excel and he needs to learn how to create a csv file and deal with the differences in date represtation in R versus Excel. At any rate he should be advised to post data in a form that people can use rather than as a picture.